# C# Custom Assembly Directory

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies, sharpdx

I have been looking for at least 3-4 hours online trying to figure out how to set a custom assembly directory. So I have quite a few DLL files from SharpDX, but they're all in the same directory as the Executable, but I want to place them in a sub-directory, such as...

Libraries
or
Bin\Libraries

I have already tried using probing in the app.config file, but didn't work. Although, here is how I set it up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="Libraries" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

P.S. My application type is a Form Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how, and what the AssemblyResolve event does. I am now posting this for those of you with the same problem I was having. So what this event does is that if it cannot find the assemblies, this event will tell it to look else where to find them. Here's how to set it up.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

private Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs e)
{
    Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Libraries\\" + e.Name.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' })[0] + ".dll");
    return ass;
}
```

Make sure to add the event out of a static method, or it will not compile. Libraries is the sub-directory in which my executable is located at. You can change that to any name, or even add another sub-directory if you please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to handle the AppDomain AssemblyResolve event.   It has proven successful for me.

Comment: Can you explain this, and show an example? Haven't been with C# for very long.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx).  In fact, if the quantity of files is what you don't like, you can embed them as resources into your application and load them directly from the resources.  For example of this see the excerpt of Jeffrey Richter's CLR Via C#: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx